# How to render block data in any page in cs-cart

Tags: php, cs-cart

How can we render any block in cs-cart using cm-ajax cm-ajax-full-render.

I tried to use cm-reload but didn't worked I also tried result_ids but still didn't worked.

In product view page how can we render product block without refreshing page.

I have already tried using jquery $.ceAjax() method but I want to do it without using it.

Like in checkout page when we change steps during checkout for making payments.

-Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two important things:

1. There div with the content which should be rendered should have the following structure:

```html
<div id="my_id"> 
content here 
<!--my_id--></div>
```

2. Your ajax request should contain result_ids parameter which should contain **my_id**

Hope this will help